# Save Webscraped data

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to scrape a website. I am able to scrape data from that website. I am having trouble saving the data from the scrape to yaml file that I have included

My Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'hpricot'

article = []
     doc = open("http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/cleared-otc/irs.html"{|f| Hpricot(f) }

      (doc/"/html/body/div/div/div/div/table/").each do |article|
      puts "#{article.inner_html}"
       end

File.open('test.yaml', 'w') { |f|
f <<article.to_yaml
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing a closing parenthesis for the `open` call (a `)` right before the block starts).

When you add that you'll notice that you'll get a `NoMethodError` (`undefined method 'to_yaml' for []:Array`). To fix that you have to `require 'yaml'`, which pulls in the monkey-patches for the `Array` class. After that you'll notice that your yaml file is empty, because you never put anything into `article`. Here's a fixed version:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'hpricot'
require 'yaml'

articles = []
url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/cleared-otc/irs.html"
doc = open(url) {|f| Hpricot(f) }

  (doc/"/html/body/div/div/div/div/table/").each do |article|
    articles << article.inner_html
  end

File.open('test.yaml', 'w') { |f| f << articles.to_yaml }
```